# How to fetch only those Contacts having photo using Cordova Plugin Contacts?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Using options.filter working well for displayName, name, emails, phoneNumbers etc and returns only matched contacts, but it is not working for photos and retuning unmatched contacts too as I want to fetch only those contacts having photos. [cordova-plugin-contacts](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts)

```
Function onSuccess (contacts) {
        console.log(contacts);
    };

function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
};

// find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter   = "content://";
options.multiple = true;
options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
var fields       = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.photos];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```